# Returning message from controller to ajax request jquery

Tags: javascript, jquery, asp.net, asp.net-mvc, asp.net-core

I have a problem getting a response from Controller back to ajax request. 
The request is done correctly, however i'm having trouble getting the message from controller to check if it was successful.

**Subject Controller code**

```
public JsonResult SaveSubjects(SubjectViewModel model) {
  bool success = false;
  if (ModelState.IsValid) {
    success = true;
    char[] years = model.Year.ToCharArray();

    for (int i = 0; i < years.Length; i++) {
      model.Year = years[i].ToString();
      Subject s = subjectGateway.FindById(int.Parse(model.Year), model.Title);
      if (s == null)
        addSubjectUseCaseFactory.AddSubjectUseCase().Execute(new AddSubjectRequestCreator().ToRequest(model));
      else {
        success = false;
        break;
      }
    }
  }
  return Json(new {
    success
  });
}
```

**JQUERY CODE**

I've added comment lines where I've confusion

```
$.ajax({
  type: "POST",
  url: '@Url.Action("SaveSubject","api/Subject")',
  data: subject,
  dataType: "html",
  success: function(subject) { // the subject gets the value "{\"success\":true}"
    debugger;
    if (subject.success) { //but here the success it says undefined.
      debugger;
      var valuesArray = new Array();
      valuesArray = selectedValue.split("");
      for (var i = 0; i < valuesArray.length; i++) {
        var select = '<select id="selectYearCell" class="form-control" width="10">' +
          '<option>5</option>' +
          '<option>6</option>' +
          '<option>7</option>' +
          '<option>8</option>' +
          '<option>9</option>' +
          '</select>';
        var row = '<tr>' +
          '<td>' + (rowIndex++) + '</td>' +
          '<td>' + title + '</td>' +
          '<td>' + valuesArray[i] + '</td>' +
          '<td>' + actions + '</td>' +
          '</tr>';

        $("#mainTable").append(row);

      }

      $("#Title").val('');
      $("#Title").removeClass("makeRed");
      $('[data-toggle="tooltip"]').tooltip();
      // $("table tbody tr").eq(index + 1).find(".add, .edit").toggle();

    } else {
      alert("Lenda ekziston");
    }
  }

});
}
```

Comment: `dataType: "application/json", contentType: "application/json"`

Comment: Check the network tab and find out the response coming back from your ajax call. Is it having the expected structure ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You Should Return like:

```
return Json(success);
```

In ajax make condition like it:

```
if (subject == true) { 
//your Code      
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Your response is a string. You should either:

1. define the dataType and contentType in the ajax request (currently you have it set to `dataType: "html"`).
2. Parse the string with `let data = JSON.parse(subject)`